# Java Spring: Efficient design of basic CRUD controller for RESTful API

Tags: java, spring, rest, crud

So let's say I have a simple entity defined as such:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldTwo;
    //...
    private String fieldN;
}
```

Let's consider a simple controller for an endpoint which handles updating Person's, but only updating fields passed in that aren't empty/blank:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/person")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updatePerson(@RequestParam("personId") Long personId, 
        @RequestParam("fieldOne") String fieldOne, 
        @RequestParam("fieldTwo") String fieldTwo, 
        //... 
        @RequestParam("fieldN") String fieldN) {
        Person toUpdate = personRepository.findOne(personId);

        if(fieldOne != null && !fieldOne.isEmpty())
            toUpdate.setFieldOne(fieldOne);
        if(fieldTwo != null && !fieldTwo.isEmpty())
            toUpdate.setFieldTwo(fieldTwo);
        //...
        if(fieldN != null && !fieldN.isEmpty())
            toUpdate.setFieldN(fieldN);

        personRepository.save(toUpdate);
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient approach for such updating of an instance of an entity? I thought about using the DTO and `@RequestBody` approach (i.e. `updatePerson(@Valid @RequestBody PersonDTO personDTO`) but this does more or less the same thing.

My main concern is that regardless of what approach I use, I obviously do not want to receive a null/empty string and set some field of an entity to be blank, but then I want to do this as efficiently as possible (efficiency in terms of code readability/portability and of course, runtime) and I'm not entirely sure if having hundreds of if-statements similar to what I have above is the most efficient option.

Answer (score 0):

The `@RequestParam` actually has another argument which is `defaultValue`, you can use this so the argument  won't never be empty & so you can reduce the checking againts empty & null values

```
@RequestParam(value="field" , defaultValue="****")
```

by using that you have already eliminated  `if(fieldOne != null && !fieldOne.isEmpty())` and calling  `toUpdate.setFieldOne(...)`that wrapping the fields directly. Using `defaultValue` automatically sets required to `false`, and inserts a *default value* into your input argument when the request parameter is missing from your URL.

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm not sure how exactly this would eliminate the need for the statements you mentioned.

Comment: Considering the url request is `/update.mvc?personId=`, the `personId` is empty but suppose the `defaultValue` is assigned to **** like `defaultValue=****`, so the personId will always has a value which is ****, it can't be empty. So you you don't need to check it through `if(personId != null && !personId.isEmpty())` but `if(personId !='****')`.

Comment: Is that really more efficient? It's a different approach, but is it really going to be more efficient? The other issue is how do I select a default value? What if I want to allow every possible string as input? What if one of my fields is an int/double/float? It's even harder then to select a default value, no?

Comment: Default value for `personId` would be `****`, so the `personRepository.findOne(..)` would return no person for the value and efficient or not each of those fields needs to be checked through `personRepository.findOne(..)` anyway, actually there is another way which is making the argument as array `public void updatePerson(@RequestParam(value="myParam") String[] myParams){ ... }` this is useful when you pass multiple parameters on the url like `/update.mvc?field1=a&field2=b&field3` , then your `myParams[0] =a`,`myParams[1]=b`,`myParams[2]=c`

Comment: So I would still have to use an if-statement for every single field? That is one of my main concerns if the entity has a bunch of fields.

Comment: Of course each one of those fields needs to be checked using that `personRepository.findOne(..)`, but you don't need to check if they are empty or null . That's why I suggested you to use `updatePerson(@RequestParam(value="myParam") String[] myParams)`, then you just need to check them via iteration (loop), because `myParam` now has a structure of  `myParams[0] =valueofField1,myParams[1]=valueofField2,myParams[2]=valueofFiel2`, this assuming the url is requested with `/update.mvc?fieldOne=itsValue&fieldTwo=itsValue&fieldThree=itsvalue`